# Vue - this.$refs is empty in mounted hook

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to access the "widgetContent" ref in my mounted hook and read the "clientHeight" property. But I awlays get this error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientHeight')".

I solved this problem using an interval and waiting until this.$refs is not empty anymore. But I don't really like the solution and wanted to ask if someone knows a better one.

This is my mounted hook:

```
mounted() {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.$refs.widgetContent) {
        this.gridHeight = this.$refs.widgetContent.clientHeight;
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 50);
  },
```

And this is the div I want to read the height from:

```
<div class="h-100" ref="widgetContent"></div>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce in a sandbox or github repo?  It's definitely not normal behavior.  A [basic example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-heyrovsky-n52wlr?file=/src/App.vue) has no issues.  Is the widgeContent div wrapped by anything that might be rendered conditionally and/or asynchronously?

Comment: Thank you, yess. The div was inside another div, which was rendered conditionally via a v-if.